# Angular - Cannot read property 'globals' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I just discovered a weird bug in my angular application (1.4.7)
When I'm on the page `/#/dashboard`, if I click on the *dashboard* link, it fails like this. Same thing happens if I click from my other pages to the related link. But it works fine if I click from dashboard to library then dashboard again. So basically, this issue only happens when I try to go to the same page where I'm right now.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'globals' of null
at ct-ui-router-extras.min.js:2
at Object.n [as forEach] (angular.js:354)
at Object.y.stateExiting (ct-ui-router-extras.min.js:2)
at Object.y.stateEntering (ct-ui-router-extras.min.js:2)
at Object.t.self.onEnter (ct-ui-router-extras.min.js:2)
at e (angular.js:4523)
at Object.a.invoke (ct-ui-router-extras.min.js:2)
at y.transition.M.then.y.transition.y.transition (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
at angular.js:14792
at r.$eval (angular.js:16052)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12520(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9292(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14800r.$eval @ angular.js:16052r.$digest @ angular.js:15870r.$apply @ angular.js:16160g @ angular.js:10589T @ angular.js:10787w.onload @ angular.js:10728
```

Here is a sample of my HTML code that generates the menu.

```
    <div class="menu-item" ui-sref-active="active">
        <a
            ui-sref="app.dashboard"
            ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }"
            translate="DASHBOARD"
        ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item" ui-sref-active="active">
        <a
            ui-sref="app.library"
            ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }"
            translate="LIBRARY"
        ></a>
    </div>
```

I'm not the one who build the product in the first place and I'm a Angular beginner. I just saw the `ui-sref-opts="{ reload: true }"`, it may be related. In the meantime, any thoughts about this behaviour? The Angular-ui stacktrace isn't helpful at all.

---

Edit: Here is the config of the `$stateProvider`: https://gist.github.com/Vadorequest/d7b1b57cd6b54f3e04a3

Comment: There should be a routeprovider or stateprovider somewhere, can you add it to your samples?

Comment: My solution was to use a specific angular attribute `ui-sref-active` and add a CSS rule `pointer-events: none` to remove the ability to click on the same menu as the active one. A simple workaround that doesn't fix the bug or explains why it happened, but now the users can't make the app crash anymore.